# Moving WordPress Multisite childsite backend broken

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I have moved hundreds of standard WordPress installations before to different domains/servers but am failing to move my first multisite installation. The front end of all the childsites work perfectly however the backend of the childsites are failing to load a lot of files (the network backend and main site backend also work perfectly)

Here is a list of the errors I am receiving in the childsite backend:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://example.com/childsite/wp-admin/load-styles.php?c=1&dir=ltr&load=dashicons,admin-bar,wp-admin,buttons,wp-auth-check&ver=4.0
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http:/example.com/childsite/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=jqu…-ui-draggable,jquery-ui-button,jquery-ui-position,jquery-ui-dialog&ver=4.0
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined debug-bar-js.js?ver=20111216:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js:6
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.validate.min.js:4
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined custom.js:8
Consider using 'dppx' units, as in CSS 'dpi' means dots-per-CSS-inch, not dots-per-physical-inch, so does not correspond to the actual 'dpi' of a screen. In media query expression: print, not all, (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25), (min-resolution: 120dpi) (index):412
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://example.com/childsite/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=hov…,svg-painter,heartbeat,wp-auth-check,jquery-form,word-count,wplink&ver=4.0
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined debug-bar.js:1
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function debug-bar-js.js?ver=20111216:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.cookie.js:17
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function debug-bar-js.js?ver=20111216:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.jcarousel.min.js:4
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function debug-bar-js.js?ver=20111216:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined main.js:1
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function debug-bar-js.js?ver=20111216:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined main-admin.js:1
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function debug-bar-js.js?ver=20111216:1
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I have replaced every old url in the database with the new url and edited wp-config. Anything else I could have forgotten?

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. I moved my live wordpress site on my local wamp server. All pages are working fine, but when see in the FireBug, some of the jQuery files were not loading due to 404 not found error. Did you find solution for this? Please share..

Comment: I believe it was down to server configuration, the server admins fixed it

Comment: Okay. I also resolved it. Some paths were required to be configured manually..